# size of multiple with ng-options for angular 1.4

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

It seems that in angular 1.4 it isn't possible to dynamically pass the value of size to a select. In 1.3 this was no problem. Anyone an idea why this is and how to work around it?

```
<select ng-model="result" ng-options="o.val as o.num + '. ' + o.val for o in test" multiple size="{{selectSize}}"></select>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brokenhip/avhfxzxk/

If you place the value hard coded it does work so if you do:

```
<select ... size="2"></select>
```

only 2 options are shown but if you set $scope.test=2; in the controller and pass it to the select as:

```
<select ... size="{{test}}"></select>
```

you see the browser default amount of options.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is trouble with simple attribute in agularjs. So when you have the opportunity, it's better to use `ng` attribute. They are specially made to works with angular. Here you have `ng-attr-size` to do the job.

There is the code coming from a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3htxgh7/)

```
<select ng-model="result" ng-options="o.val as o.num + '. ' + o.val for o in test" multiple ng-attr-size="{{selectSize}}"></select>
```